# How to reload login page after successfully logout in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

In my project after signing out i redirecting the user to go 'login' state. But if am trying to login again without refreshing the page then login is not happening. It works once i refresh the page. So please help me how to resolve this. Below am sharing the code.

**logoutController.js**

```
angular.module("adminsuite").controller("headerController",['AuthenticationService','$state','$rootScope','$cookieStore','$scope',function(AuthenticationService,$state,$rootScope,$cookieStore,$scope){
  $scope.header = $state.current.name;
  $rootScope.global = {
        search: '',
        newsurvey: false
     };
$scope.logout = function(){
                //$scope.dataLoading = true;
                AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
                $state.go('login');
                console.log($cookieStore.get('globals'));
                //$state.go('login');
            };
}]);
```

**signout.html**

```
<a ng-click='logout()'><p class="small-font"><img src = "images/signout.png" class="thumbpreImg" alt = "logoutImg"> Log out</p></a>
```

I am calling the logoutController in the signout.html page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3 options instead of `$state.go('login');`

```
$state.go('login', null, {reload: true});
```

**OR**

```
window.location.replace('/login')
```

**OR**

```
 $state.go('login');
 window.location.reload()
```

Comment: I have to write this above code in the logoutController no ??

Answer (score 1):

Add `reload: true` property.

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    //$scope.dataLoading = true;
    AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    $state.go('login', null, {reload: true});
    };
}]);
```

Comment: it is not working for me. its getting logout but if i want to login again its not loging in.

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular service to Reload your views:

- use `$route.reload()` to reload the current view (route).
- use `$location.path(newPath)` for navigating to other views.

Docs: (For Route) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Docs: (For Location)  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location